# How to wait for DataBase change to give result in Web Api Controller c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I will try to be specific as I can, because in other post I was misunderstood...

I have some Web Api controllers programmed on an Azure server for serving a mobile application.

In one of the controllers I insert some data in the database (with status 0), then I need to wait for other external call to change the status and when is changed return a json.

So resuming: I need to wait for a column on a table (with unique ID) to change before my Web Api controller continues...

I was trying to use SqlDependency but I can't get it to wait until is changed, I don't want to trigger something after is changed, I need to know if it has changed while waiting...

I need something like this:

```
int RequestStatus = await CheckRequestStatusChangeOnDB(RequestID);

if (RequestStatus == 1)
                {//do something}
if (RequestStatus == 2)
                {//do something}
if (RequestStatus == 0)
                {//no change in database, if time expired}
```

Can anyone help me please! Specifically with **CheckRequestStatusChangeOnDB**

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think you don't want an api call to wait until something on the database changes. Take a look at SignalR

Comment: Thanks @RafaelMarques ... I have tried, but can not get it to work.. Also all samples that I find contains an .OnChange function that will trigger when something changes, but that won't work for me as I need to wait while the controller is creating the response for the call. Do you have any idea how to do it? Or any link? Thanks again!